# How to redirect logs to a fifo device?

Tags: logs, rsyslog, fifo

I have the following line in the rsyslog config file:

```
*.*;auth,daemon,kern,user   -/dev/logi
```

and it does what it should, but I wanted to send some iptables logs to a different file, so I added the following content to the rsyslog.conf file:

```
:msg,contains,"IPTABLES:" /var/log/iptables
& stop
```

and I created /dev/fw device , but I have no idea how to send new content of the file to that device. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

This is the fifo device I create when system boots:

```
LOG_DEV=/dev/logi
if [ ! -r $LOG_DEV ]; then
    mkfifo $LOG_DEV
    chmod 640 $LOG_DEV
    chown root:morfik $LOG_DEV
fi
```

I just added this to the `/etc/init.d/rsyslog` file.

Having that device I can send all logs there by placing the following line in the `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file:

```
*.*                 -/dev/logi
```

It's the fist line in the rules section, so every log goes there and continues processing other rules in the config file. The next rule in that file is:

```
:msg,contains,"IPTABLES:" /var/log/iptables
& stop
```

Which sends the iptables logs to a specific file, and after doing so, rsyslog just stops processing the entries that contain `IPTABLES:` phrase. The next rules are just normal rules in the rsyslog config file.

So I just got what I wanted -- all logs are sent to the fifo device + a separate log file for iptables entries.